# Laravel: Pass object array as parameter to Controller@Method

Tags: php, laravel

So as mentioned in the title I need to call the 'store' method from 'OrdersController' with 2 parameters: $user_id (an integer), and $products(an array of objects).

Here is my code:

```
<a href="{{ route('store_orders', [$user_id, serialize($products)]) }}" class="btn btn-default">Buy!</a>
```

With the route 'store_orders':

```
Route::get('/orders/{user_id}/{products}', 'OrdersController@store')->name('store_orders');
```

And the method OrdersController@store:

```
 public function store($user_id, $products)
{
    //do something 
}
```

When I try to access the page I get the following error :

> Missing required parameters for [Route: store_orders] [URI: orders/{user_id}/{products}].

although I have the 2 parameters.

If i try with '$products' directly, instead of 'serialize($products)' I get the following error:

> Array to string conversion

If I pass as the second parameter something else than an array like:

```
<a href="{{ route('store_orders', [$user_id, $products[0]->name]) }}" class="btn btn-default">Buy!</a>
```

I don't get the error anymore and everything works fine..

Can you guys give me a solution?

P.S. sorry if I am missing any information or if I have redaction problems. It's my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{{ route('store_orders', [ 'user_id' => $user_id, 'products' => serialize($products)]) }}`?

Comment: Passing a serialized array of objects through GET may be problematic, as it may hit the length limit. I'd suggest finding another way of doing it, such as POST.

Comment: @Andrei I tried and got the exactly same errors.

Comment: @aynber has a point, not to mention the name of your method suggest a post rather than a get.

Comment: fair point. So I changed the route declaration from "Route::get..." into "Route::post.." and saw it in the route list with the 'POST' Method, but still got the same outcome. Should I change something else?

Comment: Also change the route to just use the  `user_id`, and pass the products as an input. You can make the input hidden if you want to. Or you can pass both values as inputs.

Comment: @aynber as an input?I'm not sure what you mean. Like creating a hidden form?

Comment: Yes. Create a form with hidden inputs.

Comment: ok. And what should be the value of the input in which i pass $products? Something like :  {{ Form::text('products', serialize($products), ['style' =>'visibility:hidden;']) }} ?

Comment: @aynber Ok , it worked! Thank you very much for your solution. Still curious about what was wrong with the first method. But I am so very grateful for your help :)